# Why can't certain Civimail Mailings be reused?

Tags: civimail

About half of the mailings we send are missing the "reuse" option in the action links on the "Scheduled and Sent Mailings" screen. Is this because they are sent to a search results rather than to a mailing group?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may be interested in my [resend mailing extension](https://github.com/artfulrobot/resendmailing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Re-Use link does not appear if either:

1. The user does not have at least one of the permissions (Create mailing OR access civimail)

or:

2. If the mailing was created from Find Search >> Email - schedule/send via CiviMail (which creates hidden smart group) and have Unsubscribe Group field set.

Thanks

Pradeep